# Connection between a phone and another phone

Tags: android, ios, cordova, udp

I'm working on a mobile application that takes a photo on a phone and sends it to another phone.
It should be able to work between an Android phone and an Iphone.

I'm working with phonegap. 
First I was thinking of using the bluetooth technologies, but I read that it's impossible between android and Iphone.
So I was thinking of a UDP connection, but no matter what, I can't have a server and a client on my phone.
The only things that would work is to implement a server on my Computer.

Do you know another way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Thats the normal way of doing it - get a server on the internet and build a RESTFul api to listen for a device to send/receive to a phone.  Android-to-Android, you could do NFC, but not with an iPHone